# Find string in tar.gz and extract result

Tags: linux, tar

Is there a way to find all files in a tar.gz archive containing a specific 'string', and extract these files only to a specified folder?

zgrep -a 'stringtofind' inArchive.tar.gz gives me the result in which files the string can be found, but i cannot do anything without extracting the entire archive.

Is there a way around this?

EDIT: 
I dont need to use zgrep, any option out there would suffice for me, just as its relatively fast operations

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming GNU tar, I think) You could try something like

zgrep -a 'stringtofind' inArchive.tar.gz > your.list

then

tar zxf inArchive.tar.gz --files-from=your.list

Comment: EDIT: Yeah, using GNU tar 1.23. I tried your suggestion but it doesnt really work. The > your.list just dumps the entire file content to the list and then when trying to tar using --files-from=your.list im just getting errors. Maybe this would work if i could push the filenames only to > your.list somehow?

Comment: Right. I was assuming that your zgrep already output (just) the filenames, but I suppose it does not. Hmmm.